# Trying to Install qtree

Tags: lyx, qtree

I copied the `qtree.sty` file to my `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex directory` (pretty much everywhere there, in `graphics/` , `base/` even in `qtree/`) but when I run Lyx and insert the following command LaTeX Preamble:

```
\usepackage{qtree}
```

I keep getting

> File `qtree.sty` not found

Comment: you forgot to run `texhash` tu update the data base

Comment: path was in /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex

Comment: what's the difference between texhash and mktexlsr

Comment: no difference it is the same. `texhash` is a link to `mktexlsr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put it in the main tree, but rather in the local tree:

```
sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/qtree
sudo cp qtree.sty $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/qtree/
sudo mktexlsr
```

The first command tells the system to create the required structure; the second one copies the file, the third finally tells the TeX system where to find it.

If `sudo` is not the way you act as a superuser, then use the proper method for your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

For me, if I put `\usepackage{qtree}` in the Latex Preamble (Document->Settings, select Latex Preamble from combobox) and then add a qtree tex example in my document, e.g.

Just add a tex node with this

```
\Tree [.Node1\\{Notation for Node 1} Node2\\{Notation for Node 2}  Node3\\{Notation for Node 3} ]
```

Then after hitting preview, the qtree is automatically prompted to install (using miktex on windows with lyx 2.2.3) and then the tree appears in the document.

Manually installing the package by copying files around seems like an antipattern if you can avoid it with lyx's package management